# How to: Expose C++ data structures / types (structs, enums) for usage from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, types, interop

How to expose `C++` data structures / types `(structs, enums)` for usage from `C#`.

One way is to define the equivalent types in `C#`, which is not a good way, since you have to keep them updated and in sync with the `C++` header file.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

COM interop with type libraries:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Apparently there is no way to import the data types like struct, enums in header files into managed world for reuse.
I ended up re-defining the data types in C# again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)?

This is a tool that reads your C/C++ header files and generates glue code for a number of languages, including C#.